# keep url query after refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, query-string

In my app, if the user goes to

```
http://localhost:3000/#/auth
```

The sign in page will render by default.

When the user goes to the signup page, the url is

```
http://localhost:3000/#/auth?form=signup
```

However, whenever I refresh the page, the url automatically goes back to

```
http://localhost:3000/#/auth
```

And the user now sees the sign-in page.

Is there a way to keep the url queries after a refresh? In other words, if the user is on the signup page and refreshes, I want to render the signup page and not the sign-in page.

I am using `react-router@3` and using `hashHistory`. Here is the route

```
<Route path="/auth" component={Auth} />
```

Comment: When you say "users goes to the signup page.. https://localhost:3000/#/auth?form-signup" Does the user actually get served a different page? He shouldn't... everything after the '#' is not sent to the server, so he should be served the same page each time -- http://localhost:3000/.

Comment: I have an `Auth` component that renders different forms based on the query. It is still the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what my issue is. The query string is not being cleared during refresh. I have set up a redirect based on if the user is signed in in the top level component.

```
  _redirect(isLoggedIn) {
    let route = this.props.location.pathname.slice(1);

    if (isLoggedIn) {
      this.props.router.replace('/home');
    } else if (!isLoggedIn && !/auth/.test(route)) {
      this.props.router.replace('/auth');
    }
  }
```

My issue is in the `else if` condition, I didn't check to see if the route includes `auth`. So, if the user is not logged in, this function will redirect to `/auth` and remove the query string.

```
  _redirect(isLoggedIn) {
    let route = this.props.location.pathname.slice(1);

    if (isLoggedIn && /auth/.test(route)) {
      this.props.router.replace('/home');
    } else if (!isLoggedIn && !/auth/.test(route)) { <== updated this line
      this.props.router.replace('/auth');
    }
  }
```